# Where is a shell script run from?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory

I have a shell script in `/usr/bin`. Let's call it `hello`.

It contains this:

```
 echo "I am located in $PWD"
 echo "I am called from this directory: ???"
```

Running `hello` from `/home/Documents` I expect the following output:

```
 I am located in /usr/bin
 I am called from this directory: /home/Documents
```

How can I get the directory path where the script is run from?

Comment: A Bash-specific discussion can be found in [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in) on StackOverflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can't comment on another answer, so I'm posting here. As said, `dirname` just reads `$0` and takes the directory name, so if you called something like `../../directory/something.sh` it does not resolve those dots but just returns `../../directory`. Instead of using subshell expansion with `cd` and `pwd`, you can use a very smart command `readlink` that actually resolves not only dotted directories but all symbolic links as well. I therefore suggest

```
  echo "I am located at $(readlink -e -- "$0")"
```

You may use another `dirname` around this to get the directory instead of the file.

Answer (score 6):

`$PWD` was the variable that contains the current directory. To get the directory to the shell script `$(dirname -- "$0")` can be used.

The content of the script will look like:

```
echo "I am located in $(dirname -- "$0")"
echo "I am called from this directory: $PWD"
```

Comment: another way for the 1st line (so that "./something" will not output only "." ...) : `echo "I am located in $(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"`  (don't worry, $(...) will run this in a subshell, so the cd only occurs in that subshell and will not affect the rest of the script, and thus the 2nd line will still work)

Comment: @OlivierDulac This has the benefit of always showing the absolute path.